# Can I write a file in a public folder from my iOS application?

Tags: ios

I want to know whether I can write a music file in a public folder from my iOS application? I want my file to be accessed out of my app.

Comment: The other app is developed by you?

Comment: No, for example iOS music app.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your music file in the documents folder and set "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to YES. Then you can reach the file from outside the app.

Hope this helps